# Logical operators || and && difference - I keep making mistakes

Tags: c++

I am a beginner programmer in C++ and I have trouble understanding logical operators && and ||.

For example, I had a minor assignment to write a function which returns `true` if a vector of doubles is *oscillatory* (ex.  `1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4`).

I tried a very basic solution. I made a for loop

```
for(int i=1; i<vec.size()-1; i++)
```

and an if statement which checked if the element at the i-th position is either **larger or equal to its predecessor and larger or equal to its successor** OR if the element at the i-th position is **lower or equal to its predecessor and lower or equal than its successor**

```
if ((vec.at(i) >= vec.at(i-1) && vec.at(i) >= vec.at(i+1))
 || (vec.at(i) <= vec.at(i-1) && vec.at(i) <= vec.at(i+1)))
   return false;
```

BUT this does not work! However, if I put && instead of || and || instead of && it works! Why? Here is my logic:

The result should be true if either of the sub-conditions are met (Separated by ||) because the vector of numbers cannot be oscillatory if for example the second element is greater than the first **and** greater than the third, ***OR*** if the second element is lower than the first **and** lower than the second

This is my reasoning, just put && instead of and,  after that put || instead of   or and you get my code which sadly does not work.

Can someone tell me why my logic is faulty?

Comment: there is not much magic in those operators, `||` is OR and `&&` is AND, maybe you miss to take into account operator precendence https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Your condition looks correct, but it checks for the **good** outcome. You should return `false` if this condition does **not** hold. Inverting it is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: If you do not understand the `&&` and `||`, you need a primer in Boolean algebra. It is super simple once you learn it, but if you don't, it will always be a pain. Hint - does 'truth table' mean anything to you? If it doesn't, go for Boolean algebra material.

Comment: btw I'd never write such a long condition with that many seperate terms on the first try. Instead I'd write several nested `if`s debug it carefully and only then merge it into one condition again. Alternatively, wrap the evaluation of the conditions in a function where you can do more debugging. It's never nice to have so many opportunities for errors in a single line

Comment: I think you should `return true` instead of `return false`  to solve the problem

Comment: @SergeyA Yes. I purposefully used the operator for disjunction because it returns true if either of its operands are true. In this case that's exactly what's needed right? Because the vector is not oscillatory if either of those conditions are not met

Comment: `vec.at(i) >= vec.at(i-1) && vec.at(i) >= vec.at(i+1)` basically says that the value at `i` **is** oscillatory, you need to reverse one of the equal sign.

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding of `&&` and `||` is good but your reasoning is not correct. If as you say:

> the second element is greater than the first and greater than the third, OR if the second element is lower than the first and lower than the second

...for all elements, then your vector is *oscillatory*. For a vector to not be oscillatory, you want at least one `i` where either one of these is true: `a[i - 1] <= a[i] <= a[i + 1]` or `a[i - 1] >= a[i] >= a[i + 1]`. In C++ terms:

```
if (a[i - 1] <= a[i] && a[i] <= a[i + 1] 
    || a[i - 1] >= a[i] && a[i] >= a[i + 1]) { /* ... */ }
```

Your are checking the opposite of what you want, which is why inverting the operators work.

Comment: Ah yikes. Thanks for taking your time to reply. I understand now

Answer (score 0):

> The result should be true

But you returned `false` instead. :)

Comment: OP is returning `false` because he assumed the vector is not "oscillatory" in this case, which is not right.